# Is there a way to check if a PFX cert is currently imported without getting the password

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl-certificate

I have the following script to install a PFX file:

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path .\secrets\certificates\ssl\certificate.pfx 
while($true){
    write-host "Enter Password" -foregroundcolor yellow
    try{
        $pass = read-host -AsSecureString
        $cert | Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My `
             -Exportable `
             -Password $pass
        break
    }catch{
        write-host "Incorrect password" -foregroundcolor red
        continue

    }

}
write-host "Certificate installed" -foregroundcolor green
```

However I would like to be able to run the install script again and if the cert is already installed then I don't want to ask the user once again to look up the password. It is tedious.

*Is there a way to check if a PFX file has already been imported without asking for the password?* Then I could change my code to

```
function Is-PfxInstalled($cert) {

    // ???????

}


$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path .\secrets\certificates\ssl\certificate.pfx 
if(!($cert | Is-Pfx-Installed)
{
    while($true){
        write-host "Enter Password" -foregroundcolor yellow
        try{
            $pass = read-host -AsSecureString
            $cert | Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My `
                 -Exportable `
                 -Password $pass
            break
        }catch{
            write-host "Incorrect password" -foregroundcolor red
            continue

    }

}
write-host "Certificate installed" -foregroundcolor green
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the *thumbprint* of the certificate, you can use the `Test-Path` cmdlet to check whether the certificate is installed.

Note: I renamed your function to `Test-CertificateIsInstalled` since *Test* is an *approved verb*:

```
function Test-CertificateIsInstalled 
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$Thumbprint,
        [string]$Location = 'Cert:\CurrentUser\My\'
    )

    Test-Path (Join-Path $Location $Thumbprint)
}
```

The function uses `Cert:\CurrentUser\My` as the *default* location, but you can specify a different one. Usage example:

```
Test-CertificateIsInstalled 007790F6561DAD89B0BCD85585762495E358F8A2
```

Comment: To get the thumbprint I need to ask the user for the password.

Comment: Yes, thats why I wrote that you have to *know* the thumbprint in order to use it. If you know the thumbprint of the certificate, you don't have to ask the user for the password, just use the value hard coded in your code. Or is your script not aware of *which* cert is beeing installed?

Comment: I guess I could but that is storing one extra piece of information that could get out of sync. If somebody updates the PFX file and forgets to update the thumbprint then it's a mess. Are you sure there is no way to check the PFX file is imported without first either having the thumbprint or having the password?

Comment: Im not sure but im not aware of any way to retrieve the thumbprint of a pfx *without* a password. I also understand your concerns about get out of sync. Alternative, you can use another property of your certificate like the * Subject* to check whether its installed. But then you have a problem if you wan't to update an expired certificate....

Comment: You cannot access certificates in pfx without using password, because certificates and keys in pfx are usually encrypted and protected by password.